# Issue running vim as a root

Tags: linux, vim, nerdtree

If this question is not considered to have this place in this forum, tell me I will remove it instantly !

I have installed on my ubuntu a vim plugin (called NERDTree). It works well when I open a file  with a non-root status. When I run vim as a root and I try to launch the plugin with :NERDTree, I am told the command 'NERDTree' is unknown. Someone could help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install the NERDTree plugin in your home `~/.vim/plugins` directory?  If so, then the root user probably doesn't "see" it.  Move it to the global plugins directory and that should fix it.

Comment: Could you tell where is the 'global plugin directory' located ?

Comment: On my Ubuntu computer, it's located at /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin .  You might need to change vim73 to what version you're running.

Comment: Thanks a lot I didn't know about this vim plugin global directory

Answer (score 3):

Plugins placed in `/usr/share/vim/vim7x` will most likely be overwritten at the next upgrade. If you want your plugins to be available to root you should install them in `/root/.vim`.

That said, Vim comes by default with a file explorer plugin called netrw. You may try to learn how to use it (`:h netrw`) before installing any third party replacement.